# How to Update database rows by html table with inputs

Tags: php, sql, html-table

[image]

I have html table where stocks are listed with their first and second prices by php from database as you can see in the image.

The checkbox, first price and second price columns are inputs with id and price values and checkboxes are checked when table listed.

Shortly i want to update prices even if i change the prices or not.

Here is my html table created by php query:

```
<td align="center" width="10%"><input type="checkbox" name="sto_RECno[]" 
value='.$sto_RECno.' checked/></td>

<td align="left" width="50%">'.$sto_isim.'</td>

<td width="20%"><input style="text-align:right" class="input1" type="text" 
name="sto_satis_fiyat[]" value="'.$sto_satis_fiyat.'"></td>

<td width="20%"><input style="text-align:right" class="input1" type="text" 
name="sto_satis_fiyat1[]" value="'.$sto_satis_fiyat1.'"></td>
```

Here is my php code to update which is not working.

```
if(isset($_POST['sto_RECno']) && isset($_POST['sto_satis_fiyat']) && 
isset($_POST['sto_satis_fiyat1'])) {

$urunler            = implode(', ', $_POST['sto_RECno']);

$birinci_fiyatlar   = implode(', ', str_replace(',', '.', 
$_POST['sto_satis_fiyat']));

$ikinci_fiyatlar    = implode(', ', str_replace(',', '.', 
$_POST['sto_satis_fiyat1']));

$toplu_guncelleme =  mysql_query("UPDATE stoklar SET sto_satis_fiyat = 
'".$birinci_fiyatlar."', sto_satis_fiyat1 = '".$ikinci_fiyatlar."', 
sto_lastup_date = '".$sto_lastup_date."' WHERE sto_RECno IN 
('".$urunler."')");}
```

Anybody has any idea why i can not update prices if i change even one stocks price?

Comment: 1. **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. **You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: Are  you using PHP to echo your HTML?

Comment: Thanks for information but i know all these changes. But now i need help about my problem.

Comment: Looks to me like you are trying to store comma seperated lists in a single column in MySQL. That is a bad idea, just think how you are going to process that data once its in the database. Take it from me, you wont like doing it

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson yes i use php query.

Comment: Then you should change the code to use pdo or mysqli and prepared statements first. There's no reason to spend time debugging code that still would need to be rewritten. If you rewrite it, it might actually solve your issue (and you can add proper error handling as well that might tell you what the issue is, while you're at it).

Comment: What is a "php query"? Do you mean echo?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't use comma seperated values in one column. both prices are in different columns in database table.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson yes echo

Comment: Yes you do!!! You store ALL the `$_POST['sto_RECno']` in a comma seperated list in a single column and ALL the `$_POST['sto_satis_fiyat']` in a comma seperated list in a single column etc etc

Comment: You're actually creating three comma separated strings (your `implode()`'s).

Comment: What did you think [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) did?

Comment: I think it might be a good time to archive this code, do a few basic Relational Database tutorials, and a few PHP tutorials and then start again

Comment: Ok. Thanks both of you. I will try to get more information and write the code in mysqli and try again..